# No line breaks in tags in tag cloud

Tags: tags

I use the tag cloud widget on my site. I have some tags which consist of more than one word, like 'free will'. In the tag cloud, there sometimes comes a line break *in* those tags, between the words:

[image]

How can I make that this doesn't happen? I thought of adding `display:inline-block;` to the style of the tags, but there is no general `tag` class or something like that. Can I add a class to all tags (and if so how?) or is there an other way to do this (and if so what way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your CSS (untested, but should work in theory)

```
.tagcloud a {
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This answer was "flagged as low-quality because of its length and content", which I am sure you don't want. Please try to provide some explanation along with your answer to avoid that.

Comment: There really isn't anything more to add. Penalizing conciseness is rather an odd policy.

Comment: Concise isn't the point. I can look at code in several languages and work out what it is doing, but the person asking the question likely cannot-- hence the question. The idea is to provide reaonably complete answers to questions, not just raw code dumps.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the notification of this answer. Works like a charm, thanks!